# Weird UITableViewCell Loading Exception

Tags: iphone, debugging, uitableview

In my app, I use a custom NIB to load my UITableViewCells. The NIB's File's Owner is set so the class is my View Controller. I then Link the UITableViewCell to the IBOutlet I put in the header file. It was all working fine, until all of the sudden it stopped working, and gets this error:

```
uncaught exception 'NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException', reason: '*** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver decodeObjectForKey:]: cannot decode object of class (UITableViewCellContentView)'
```

I have traced this exception to [NSBundle loadNibNamed:owner:options:]

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"SubjectCell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SubjectCell" owner:self options:NULL];
cell = customSubjectCell;
```

I have tried this on two devices and the simulator, but all get the same error. I downloaded the new SDK today, and I think that may have caused this.

---

**PLEASE NOTE:**

This question is outdated, and the fix below was a temporary fix. Apple has fixed its SDK, so if you have the newest version of the SDK this *does not* apply to you.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Found solution in dev forums

Create this files:

UITableViewCellContentView.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface UITableViewCellContentView : UIView {
}
@end
```

UITableViewCellContentView.m

```
#include "UITableViewCellContentView.h"
@implementation UITableViewCellContentView

+ (id)alloc {
    return [UIView alloc];
}

+ (id)allocWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {
    return [UIView allocWithZone:zone];
}

@end
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It was starting to drive me crazy!! (there's a "@end" missing at the end of the .h file though)

Comment: Thanks a ton! This works! but why is it breaking existing projects?

Comment: WANING: Do not use this in shipping apps.  It's a private class that Apple will likely not want you monkeying with.  This is a known bug in 3.2 SDK which will get fixed.  It's best not to install beta SDKs over your current one.  Install to a different location so you can play around, but reserve your current SDK for work that needs to ship today.

Comment: If you need to ship code for SDK 3.0 but can't because of above bug, what do you do?

Answer (score 7):

Uh oh. I'm having the same issue... Also using today's new SDK (01/28/2010). Can't say for sure whether the code was working before, because I just added it AFTER updating to the new SDK.

Anybody else seeing this issue now? Any solutions?

**Update**: I just switched the simulator to SDK 3.2 (from 3.12), and whattaya know... it's working now (in the iPhone and iPad simulator). However, it doesn't work when compiling using SDK 3.12.

**My guess is that IB is saving the XIB in a new format for 3.2 perhaps? Anybody know how to force it to save in the old (3.12) format?  This definitely feels like a bug, as it's breaking previously working code.**

Answer (score 1):

I had the same thing. Installed 3.2 beta from 3.1.2 and had this error.

In the end this fixed it: Rebuild against Simulator 3.1 and I got a working build in the simulator. After this, builds against Simulator 3.1.2 work.