# NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException: cannot decode object of class (UITableViewCellContentView)

Tags: iphone, exception

my App is failing on startup, i located the issue to the following code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";
MyIdentifier = @"tblCellView";

TableCellView *cell = (TableCellView *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
if(cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[TableCellView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] autorelease];
            NSLog(@"this is working----");
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TableCellView" owner:self options:nil];
           NSLog(@"this is not working----");
    cell = tblCell;
}    

return cell;
```

}

But what am i doing wrong?

The Error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException', reason: '*** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver decodeObjectForKey:]: cannot decode object of class (UITableViewCellContentView)'
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Try to save `TableCellView.nib` again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution: [Weird UITableViewCell Loading Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2152321/weird-uitableviewcell-loading-exception)

Its a 3.2 SDK Beta Bug!